# How can I test tab order with ruby selenium/capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I need to write a series of test to verify tab order on different pages in my web-app. The issue that I'm facing is that as far as I can tell, the `send_keys` method for capybara requires you to be on a specific element. Let me illustrate with a very simple example.

```
<div class="group">
  <input type="text" id="first">
  <input type="text" id="second">
  <input type="text" id="third">
</div>
```

On my page (call it www.mypage.com/home) I have three input fields as shown above. What I would like to do is go to the page and verify that as I tab through it goes from first to second to third... So essentially I would like to do:

```
visit 'www.mypage.com/home'
send_keys(:tab)
expect(find('#first')).to have_focus
send_keys(:tab)
expect(find('#second')).to have_focus
send_keys(:tab)
expect(find('#third')).to have_focus
```

The issue, as I mentioned above, is that capybara requires me to be on a specific element. So while I can test that it goes from first to second and second to third using the code below, I don't know how to verify the first thing tabbed to is `first`. Additionally the code below has a bunch of extra lookups.

```
page.find('#first').send_keys(:tab)
expect(find('#second')).to have_focus
page.find('#second').send_keys(:tab)
expect(find('#third')).to have_focus
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial tab key press has to be sent somewhere so pick something, like the body element, and send it to that.  From there on you know the element that has focus and where you'd like to send the key, so just find them once and use them (rather than repetitive finding)

```
visit 'www.mypage.com/home'
first, second, third = find('#first'), find('#second'), find('#third')
find('body').send_keys(:tab) # or find('*:focus'), etc.
expect(first).to have_focus
first.send_keys(:tab)
expect(second).to have_focus
second.send_keys(:tab)
expect(third).to have_focus
```